# $\sigma$-algebra generated by a function having as target a Borel space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X, Y$ be sets, $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a function and suppose we have a set of subsets of $Y$, $\tau$; unless the answer to my question requires it, I think $\tau$ can be arbitrary, not necessarily a topology.

Let $H : = \sigma(\{ f^{-1}(U): U \in \tau \})$ and $G := \left\{ f^{-1}(M): M \in \sigma(\tau) \right\}$. Is it true that $H = G$?

I can see that $H \subseteq G$ because $\{f^{-1}(M): M\in \sigma(\tau) \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra by set theoretic stuff, which contains $\{ f^{-1}(U): U \in \tau \}$.

But I can't find an argument for the converse inclusion. If I take $G'$ another $\sigma$-algebra containing $\{ f^{-1}(U): U \in \tau \}$, can I show that $G \subseteq G'$? Probably yes, exploiting that $\sigma(\tau)$ is smallest, but I can't see how.

The in the original context in which I saw this, $Y = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tau$ is the usual euclidian topology. So if it's not true in general, what about this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach for the converse is a good one. Consider the set $\mathcal{A} := \{M\subseteq Y\colon f^{-1}(M) \in G’\}$. Check each of the conditions for $\mathcal{A}$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$, and you will see that it is one.

Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\tau$, it must contain $\sigma(\tau)$. This means that $G’$ contains $\{f^{-1}(M)\colon M\in \sigma(\tau)\}$. In particular, this means that $G \subseteq H$.